# How to change settings in Netbeans 6.5 to run web application in not default browser?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.5

I use Firefox as default browser in my computer.

I need to develop the web application(JSP) project in Netbeans 6.5 and everytime I run the project, it run in Firefox.

I want to run my web application in IE for testing but not change my default web browser.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Netbeans 6.5 under Tools->Options->General there's an option on top called Web Browser. Did you try to change that? Doesn't that work for you?

[Edit]: Maybe you have to make changes [that way](http://wiki.netbeans.org/TaT_FixExternalWebBrowserInRCPApp)

Comment: and also applies to 8.2

Answer (score 3):

I just discovered something that isn't mentioned here and I though I would share. My NetBeans configuration (Tools >> Options >> General) showed my browser as "Default System Browser" and it seems that it did not pick up Chrome as my default browser. Needless to say when xdebug was called it did not know which browser to open. I changed it to my only other option which was Internet Explorer and voila! Just the basic configuration of downloading the correct xdebug file and setting the path and the other 4 common options in the "correct" php.ini. There is an option to edit the list to include other browsers as well, but only one at a time.

My system is windows 7, xampp and the latest version of netbeans and xdebug as of december 2011. This flags will also help other users with a similar config find this post. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Tools> Options> General

click on "Edit" button to add the browser path and change the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Tools > Options > General

Click on the "Edit" button to add the browser path and change the default browser.

After choosing the Chrome browser, then choose the IDE default browser. This will work.